# Is there a way to still display shape outline even when NaN data are present in my map?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to display state csv data in a map format and annotate the states with data. Some states do not have data (nan), and when I make a plot, these states with no data disappear. I want those states to appear still, but just be blank. I tried using the fillna("") function, but now my colormap does not display properly, and decimals ".0" appear after each label. Below is my code:

```
csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Downloads\Data.csv')
sf = r'C:\Downloads\s_11au16\s_11au16.shp'
US = gpd.read_file(sf)

#Merge them
data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(csv.merge(US)).fillna("")
#set projection
df1 = data.to_crs(epsg=6923)
df1

#set up basemap
ax = df1.plot(figsize = (12,8), column="data", cmap="Greens", edgecolor='k', linewidth=.5, vmin=40, vmax=80)
ax.set_axis_off()

#annotate
df1.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['data'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', fontsize=14,path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=3, foreground="white")]), axis=1)
```

[Output map result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcm2Q.png)

Therefore, is there any way I can attain my colormap back and get rid of decimals after my labels when using the fillna("") function? Or is there another way to do this? Below is another image of what the map looks like without the fillna("") function embedded. I would like these nan labels removed but having those state boundaries back in there, and decimals removed as well.

[Output 2, without fillna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXOyr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on plotting with missing data https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html#missing-data. You need to specify `missing_kwds` containing styles as they cannot be inferred from data.

```py
ax = df1.plot(
    figsize = (12,8), 
    column="data", 
    cmap="Greens", 
    edgecolor='k', 
    linewidth=.5, 
    vmin=40, 
    vmax=80, 
    missing_kwds={
        "color": "lightgrey",
        "edgecolor": "k",
        "label": "Missing values",
    },)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Though, nan is still labeled in the states, and decimal places still appear in all labels. Any workaround for either of these issues? @martinfleis

Comment: @chisox create a new column that fills the null values with an empty string